# Can the default tab for a Microsoft Teams site be changed?

Tags: microsoft-teams

When I open my Microsoft Teams site, the "Conversations" tab will always show first.  Is there a way to make the "Wiki" or "Files" tab appear first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a programming question, but I'll answer it anyway.

The answer is no, and we aren't likely to get to it anytime soon even though it does get asked for. The reason is that if the tab order is dynamic, we have to hit the disk or the network in order to start rendering, which will kill our channel switch time.

Comment: By "hit the disk" do you mean "read a simple variable from the disk or network"?  Is that enough to crash the app?